# How to toggle vertical tabs with vertical text and content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This code is displaying vertical tabs with vertical text and content. Toggle is not working properly, when I click on second tab, first content is also displaying. Can anyone help me to get the content of individual tabs? Here I have mentioned html, css and javascript code. Is it possible in Jquery? Can anyone mention the details?

```
<main id="main">       
<section id="portfolio"> 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
    <div class="vtab">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left vertical-text">
              <li class="active"><a href="#home-v" data-toggle="tab">Home</a> 
               </li>
              <li><a href="#profile-v" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
             </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
          <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="left" >
                    <div>
          <ul id="tree1" >
                    <li id="li2">News
                  <ul>
                      <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                      <li>Employees
                          <ul>
                              <li>Reports
                                  <ul>
                                      <li>Report1</li>
                                      <li>Report2</li>
                                      <li>Report3</li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>Human Resources</li>
                  </ul>
              </li>

               <li id="li2">Sites
                  <ul>
                      <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                      <li>Employees
                          <ul>
                              <li>Reports
                                  <ul>
                                      <li>Report1</li>
                                      <li>Report2</li>
                                      <li>Report3</li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>Human Resources</li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="profile-v">Profile Tab.</div>
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>    
        </div>    
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.fn.extend({
    treed: function (o) {

      var openedClass = 'glyphicon-minus-sign';
      var closedClass = 'glyphicon-plus-sign';

      if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
        if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
        }
        if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
        }
      };
        var tree = $(this);
        tree.addClass("tree");
        tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
            var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
            branch.prepend("<i class='indicator glyphicon " + closedClass + "'></i>");
            branch.addClass('branch');
            branch.on('click', function (e) {
                if (this == e.target) {
                    var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                    icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                    $(this).children().children().toggle();
                }
            })
            branch.children().children().toggle();
        });
      tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('li').click();
        });
      });
        tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
});

$('#tree1').treed();
```

```
  <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  <link 
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
 <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap- 
 combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter- 
        bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please post a working jsfiddle or codepen link?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/avpyg9d2/21/)

Comment: please find the above link in jsfiddle. when i click on profile tab only content in that div should display but here first tab content is also displaying, how to achieve it in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot both import of jQuery (JSfiddle console raised that error) and Boostrap classes (tab-pane) and ids (the content of the href of the *a* tag) on tabs panels.

Here the right code:

jQuery Script from CDN:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
```

Here the right panel code:

```
<section id="portfolio">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
            <div class="vtab">
               <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <hr/>
                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left vertical-text">
                     <li class="active"><a href="#home-v" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#profile-v" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-9">
                  <!-- Tab panes -->
                  <div class="tab-content">
                     <div class="tab-pane" id="home-v">Home Tab.</div>
                     <div class="tab-pane" id="profile-v">Profile Tab.</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

I simplified the code inside the Home panel in order not to post a big piece of code, which was not relevant.

Hope this helps!

Working [codepen link](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/OEEgqo) with full code.

Comment: The tree structure in home tab is not displaying for me, profile tab shows its content.

Comment: Check the codepen, there you can see your full code.

Comment: Basically add jQuery, just change <div id="left"> with <div class="tab-pane" id="home-v"> and you're done.

Comment: but removing id=left will remove my entire tree structure nothing is displaying in code pen also only profile tab showing profile content.

Comment: You cannot have multiple IDs and the one you need is, as I said, the content of the href of the tag a. Use a class instead of the ID. By the way, in my codepen if I click on HOME I can see tree structure......

Comment: Thank You, i too find tree structure on clicking home but why it is not showing when page is loading i mean starting itself only after clicking the home tab it is showing how to do it if i need the tree immediate after page load?

Comment: Oh sorry, just add the class "active" to the <div class="tab-pane" id="home-v">, I've updated the pen :)

Comment: Yes, This is working pretty good but when I tried to put this in my whole web page for first clicks of both buttons its working good but when I click on the buttons twice    the second content is coming below the first content and the first content is hiding how to make the second content to replace the first content? it's working perfect separately but in whole web page it is not properly aligning.

Comment: Try to add in the js fiddle all the JS and CSS you have. Otherwise close this question since I help you fixes and create a new one specific for the new problem:)